# OpenLayers 6 + Angular 8 : LineString(s) not showing up on Vector Layer (With no errors from JS)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I'm having an issue where my LineString(s) aren't showing up on the map and the console isn't giving out any errors.

I belive my code is correct but i'm not that bright when it comes to OpenLayers and i may be wrong.

This is how i add my Vector Layer to the map

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      name: 'trailLayer',
      type: "Vector",
      source: new ol.source.Vector({ format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({ featureProjection:"EPSG:3857" }) }),
      zoomMin: 8,
      zoomMax: 18
    });

    this.map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Than this is what I do to add a new LineString

```
let layer;
this.map.getLayers().forEach(function (value) { if ( value.get('name') === 'trailLayer') { layer = value; } });
if(layer == null) { return; }

let coords = [[latA, lonA], [latB, lonB]];
let lineString = new ol.geom.LineString(coords);
lineString.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

var lineFeature = new ol.Feature({
    name: callsign,
});

lineFeature.setGeometry(lineString);


var lineStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        width: trailWidth,
        color: trailColor
    })
});

lineFeature.setStyle(lineStyle);

layer.getSource().addFeature(lineFeature);
```

If I try to use `source.GetFeatures()` it shows all my features correctly, but I can't see them on the map.

Am I missing something?

P.S. Every variable is assigned correctly, nothing strange and no undefined ecc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OL the coordinates must be [expressed](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/faq.html#why-is-the-order-of-a-coordinate-lon-lat-and-not-lat-lon-) as longitude first, then latitude.

Try swapping the coordinates:

```
let coords = [[lonA, latA], [lonB, latB]];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was going crazy